# Change child of key in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have several firebase keys in my database like so

```
key1 {
  name: joe
} 
key2 { 
  name: anne 
} 
key3 { 
  name: joe
}
```

I want to change the name of all the keys that contain the name "joe" to "will".

So something like this:

```
myRef.(...).hasChild("joe").update({
    name: will
});
```

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: that is not the best design choice.

Comment: how so? The Firebase introductory tutorial has the same design concept.

Comment: suppose users can change names and user joe decide to change his name  which as result means you have to go through all keyX nodes and search for "joe". you better do it via reference.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? The users won't be able to change names.

Comment: your question was about changing name from joe to will :)   I would do: joe:{key1, key3}

Comment: aha yes, but they won't be able to manually do it themselves. I see what you mean. Basically each key is a message, so if you suggest that I do joe{key1, key3} and anne{key2} how would I go about displaying all of the keys from every user? (like a global message chat)

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase's JavaScript/Web SDK this is fairly simple.

Say that you have a Firebase ref to the node **above** key1, key2 and key3.

```js
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/parentofkeys');
```

Then you can create a query that contains just the keys whose name property is Joe:

```js
var query = ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo('joe');
```

And then update all current (and future) Joe's using:

```js
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().update({ name: 'will' });
});
```

Please thoroughly study the relevant sections of Firebase's documentation:

- [Updating saved data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-update)
- [Read event types](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types)
- [Querying data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Note that these are all part of [Firebase's Web Development Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). It might be a good idea if you follow through that guide step by step.